# YouTube API ListResponse ETag inconsistency

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Responses to an identical `commentThread` list requests where another page of results exist return different `etag` values for the `commentThreadListResponse`.

When the requests are made and all items are returned in the first page of results, (i.e. no `nextPageToken` is supplied with the response), the responses' `etag` values are unchanged (and hence useful).

The result of this is that caching of list requests (often the most costly) is useless unless the entire list result set is returned in one page - even if the result set is identical.

Is anyone aware that this is a bug or expected performance? Does anyone know a route to make etags useful for list requests?

It seems to me that it's likely the `etag` generation for the list response includes the `nextPageToken` in it's hashing strategy, as the `nextPageToken` is different for each response.